# What documents should I have when entering Kuwait on a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, kuwait

Should an Indian passport holder carry the original visit visa documents or is a copy of the valid visa enough while travelling from Canada to Kuwait?

Answer (score 1):

To board the plane, you need to show a **copy** of the visa. The original visa should be deposited at the airport by the receiving party (there is desk for this in the arrivals hall).

You don't need a return ticket or hotel reservation.

On arrival, walk to the visa desk. Give the officer the copy of your visa, they will then confirm your arrival and hand you the original. Walk to the immigration counters and get stamped into the country.

Answer (score -1):

These documents are needed

- Kuwait Visa
- Hotel Reservation / Stay details (You need to provide that address in immigration form)
- Return Ticket

If you are transiting, make sure transit visas are there, if applicable (esp Heathrow).